# Como mexer em código em uma DLL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, dll, c#

O código de barras está sendo gerado através de uma classe de uma DLL baixada da internet. Preciso alterar esse código de barras, mas essa classe é bloqueada. Como posso fazer uma gambiarra?

Comment: Não faça uma gambiarra. Altere a classe original no GitHub, teste-a localmente, depois mande um *pull request* para o autor. Precisa de um roteiro?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, é uma classe do BoletoNet, onde eu já tinha/tenho um boleto do santander, precisei criar um do bradesco. Consegui alterar algumas informações, mas o principal que é o código de barras não dá.

Comment: [O que é engenharia reversa?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/112852/20615)

Comment: BoletoNet é um software aberto e livre. Você pode baixar o fonte e compilar. Aí a classe não fica bloqueada. E o melhor: se você fizer algo que seja útil pra você, é provável que seja útil pro resto da comunidade também. Aí você pode subir sua modificação e todo mundo vai usar ela e te amar. Segue o link do repositório: https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro, é pouco provável que precise mexer no código de barras. Isto é algo padronizado e se está pronto, mexer provavelmente só estragará.

Classe bloqueada é termo que eu desconheço mas vou entender que você não consegue mexer nela por alguma razão.

Se você só tema DLL e não existe uma forma de acessar uma API dela, tem pouco a fazer.

Não dá para ajudar muito com tão poucas informações. Nem sabemos do que você está falando.

Se não tem o código, existe a possibilidade de descompilá-lo, mexer o que precisa e recompilar. Mas não é algo tão simples, o código fica bem ruim, não é fácil mexer nele e dependendo do caso estará fazendo algo ilegal.

Se tem o código não precisa de nenhuma gambiarra, é só alterar o código que possui.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: É uma classe daquele BoletoNet, eu consegui mudar algumas coisas e transformar de santander pra bradesco. Mas o principal que é o código de barras não dá pra mudar pq está sendo carregado direto em uma classe que é metadata.

Comment: É que você não dá detalhes sobre isto, então não é fácil ajudar mas deve ser alguma mudança no código que precisa fazer e você não fez. Até onde eu vi o código gera o código digitável para o Bradesco e o código de Barras é padrão para todos os bancos e não precisa ser mexido.

Comment: Ahhh não sabia disso. Mas tem uma pasta que contem varias imagens de codigos de barras diferentes. Eu pensei que eu teria que passar alguma imagem diferente da que carrega no boleto do santander.

Comment: Certamente não é isso, isto deve ser exemplos apenas, não é para ter os códigos de barras prontos, eles terão que ser gerados na hora, afinal cada código tem um número diferente, caso contrário não faria sentido ter as barras lá se fossem iguais para todos boletos. O padrão dos bancos no Brasil é o [Interleaved 2 of 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interleaved_2_of_5)

Comment: Ahh, só pra ver se eu entendi, nesse caso então é aquele numero em cima, no começo do boleto no canto superior direito, correto ?

Comment: Acho que é isso. Esse número é que é diferente não só para cada boleto, óbvio mas a maneira de calcular de cada banco também. E até onde eu vi, tem para todos os principais bancos. O código de barras é apenas uma representação em barras deste número. O jeito de fazer as barras é padronizado e não precisa mexer nele.

Comment: Consegui entender. Obrigado, ajudou bastante.