# O que é Engenharia Reversa?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, engenharia-reversa

Costumo sempre dizer que não me dou muito bem com termos.

Esses dias atrás precisei fazer uma operação num determinado framework em *PHP* chamado *Laravel*, onde eu precisava encontrar um recurso que me permitiria usar um banco já existente e fazer com que ele gerasse automaticamente os *models* e *migrations* da aplicação através das tabelas desse banco.

Geralmente o que ocorre é o contrário: Você gera *models* e *migrations*, que, por sua vez, geram o banco de dados.

Fiz várias pesquisas na internet (em inglês) para poder encontrar o que eu  queria, porém não encontrava. Até que eu usei o termo *Database Reverse Engine for Laravel*, e encontrei o que procurava.

Até então eu não estava tão familiarizado com o termo, por pensar em se tratar em algo muito distante do meu dia-a-dia de programação. Mas parece que não era verdade.

O que eu entendo pela experiência que tive é que Engenharia Reversa está relacionado a usar o que foi gerado para criar o gerador. Me corrijam se eu estiver errado.

É por isso que venho aqui perguntar: O que é exatamente a Engenharia Reversa?

**Nota:** Não vou incluir a tag `php` ou `laravel`, pois não se trata do assunto, foi apenas um exemplo.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como proteger o código fonte](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7257/como-proteger-o-c%C3%B3digo-fonte)

Comment: Desmontar um brinquedo, por exemplo, é engenharia reversa.

Comment: Uma coisa interessante a se notar é que a palavra _reverse_, como adjetivo, não se traduz para _reverso_ e sim para _invertido_ ou _ao contrário_. Ou seja, _engenharia reversa_ (assim como _instância_ ) são neologismos de programação no português.

Comment: Desmontar algo para saber como aquilo foi feito, para depois utilizar o conhecimento obtido, e tentar fazer igual, ou parecido. Há quem diga que os chineses fazem isso, para criar seus eletrônicos falsificados. Em computação, significa desfazer o processo de compilação, e obter novamente o código fonte.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Engenharia reversa, em termo leigo, nada mais é do que descobrir como o programa funciona com o programa acabado.¹

Para realizar a engenharia reversa deve-se analisar o produto concluído e verificar "como ele foi construído". Como o @rray [disse nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112817/o-que-%C3%A9-engenheria-reversa#comment234246_112819), o crack de jogos é um bom exemplo disso. Claro, feito para o "mal" (para os fabricantes e bem para nós, rsrs), mas é um ótimo exemplo.

Há relatos que empresas utilizam engenharia reversa para verificar os produtos das concorrentes, seja em software ou não. Como a briga eterna entre a [Apple vs Samsung](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=samsung%20reverse%20engineering%20apple) sobre roubo de informações e quebra de patentes se encaixa neste meio. Neste caso podemos ver que a engenharia reversa não está limitado apenas em códigos, mas sim em diversas áreas, neste exemplo em específico, hardware também.

### Mas e aí, é difícil fazer Engenharia Reversa?

Isso depende muito de suas qualidades e do que quer fazer.

Um exemplo fácil é o  uso do [.NET Reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) para obter o código fonte de dll's .NET. Veja abaixo uma imagem de exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste exemplo estou apenas verificando o que está por trás da dll **System.Xml.Linq.dll**, da Microsoft. Isso foi possível apenas com 2 cliques com o programa, nada de difícil, não concorda?

### E re-engenharia, é a mesma coisa?

Hoje existe uma grande confusão sobre engenharia reversa e re-engenharia (refatoração).
Re-engenharia nada mais é do que que examinar um produto acabado e construir de novo, mas com melhorias¹.

Em resumo, engenharia reversa você obtém como foi feito, seja para qual for o objetivo, Dark Side ou não. Já na re-engenharia você apenas melhora, e não necessariamente precisa de fazer uma engenharia reversa para obter os fontes.

### Está dizendo que todos tem acesso ao meus fontes então?

De certa forma, sim.
Você não consegue "impossibilitar" de conseguirem o seu código, mas da para dificultar.

[Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7257/20615) do @Math possui excelentes respostas sobre isso, então não entrarei em mais detalhes. :p

---

¹ [What is the difference between re-engineering and reverse engineering?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/877751/4843158)

Comment: Concordo com quase tudo, só não entendo com um "crack" pode fazer bem? Ao meu ver a escolha dos direitos de uso/reprodução de um software/game é de quem o faz e não de quem quer usufrui-lo.

Comment: @Jean Essa parte foi uma piada, desculpe se não fui mais claro. Mas o crack vai muito além do que uma simples engenharia reversa, o que seria muito amplo para ser tratado em uma única resposta. Existem N fatores que podem influenciar nesse assunto.

Comment: @Randrade da próxima vez adiciona a tag `<sarcasm>` ou `<ironic>`, para que alguém não pense que você está fazendo apologia. É claro que pelo conteúdo do texto fica nítido que você não quis fazer isso

Answer (score 20):

É o fluxo inverso ao da engenharia de uma solução.

O fluxo tradicional pode ser expresso da seguinte maneira:

<kbd>Especificação</kbd> `>` <kbd>Arquitetura</kbd> `>` <kbd>Implementação</kbd> `>` <kbd>Comportamento</kbd>

Engenharia reversa, neste caso, é *quando a especificação é deduzida a partir do comportamento*:

<kbd>Comportamento</kbd> `>` <kbd>Implementação</kbd> `>` <kbd>Arquitetura</kbd> `>` <kbd>Especificação</kbd>

Este é um princípio largamente utilizado em implementação de soluções, como consequência de várias situações:

- Uma solução legada e que não pode ser mais alterada diretamente ainda precisa receber entrada de dados: Um profissional pode analisar a API ou interfaces da aplicação, e escrever uma solução que publique dados no formato esperado. (Este processo é tão frequente que até recebe um nome: [Brokerage](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1103636?tstart=0).)
- Uma solução baseada em APIs na Web pode ter seu comportamento estudado, e novos clientes podem ser escritos (casos de exemplo: [DropBox](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/researchers-reverse-engineer-the-dropbox-client-what-it-means/), [Yik Yak](https://github.com/SuperSpyTX/Hack-Yak))

Comment: Desconhecia o termo **Brokerage**. Foi bom conhecer!

Answer (score 17):

Engenharia Reversa é o processo de, a partir do todo, compreender as partes, o funcionamento, os princípios de algo. É um termo que foi cunhado para o hardware, entretanto, é amplamente aplicado ao software.

Exemplo: Ao desmontar um rádio é possível compreender muita coisa a respeito do seu funcionamento. Quais componentes eletrônicos ele usa, como esses componentes estão interligados, os módulos, etc. É muito comum que empresas comprem dispositivos de outras para desmontar e entender os tipos de compomentes que foram utilizados. Na guerra entre Apple e Samsung vários celulares foram destruídos com esse propósito.

No software, esse termo é aplicado em vários contextos. Exemplos não faltam:

- Gerar os códigos de criação de um banco de dados a partir das tabelas e relacionamentos já criados;
- Compreender um protocolo de rede específico a partir dos pacotes de rede. Um exemplo clássico é o Samba, um software que permite que sistemas operacionais Linux compartilhem arquivos e impressoras com máquinas Windows.
- Compreender um formato de arquivo específico. Um exemplo clássico é o OpenOffice, pois ele consegue abrir planilhas e documentos do Office (principalmente antes do Office 2007, já que era um formato binário).

Comment: Neste caso o Wine também faz parte deste contexto? Com ele podemos executar aplicativos `.exe` do Windows no Linux.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho, sem dúvida o Wine é um exemplo de Engenharia Reversa. Os desenvolvedores do Wine tiveram que entender bastante coisa sem nenhum tipo de documentação ou mesmo suporte da Microsoft para implementar o Wine e conseguir executar binários do Windows no Linux. Bem lembrado.

Answer (score 16):

Engenheria reversa é o processo contrário do habitual seja no desenvolvimento de software ou não, a partir de algo já gerado obter acesso ou descobrir como algo foi feito sem ter o conhecimento interno ou seja é como identificar os componentes, a forma/ordem de montagem de uma caixa preta, isso pode ser feito de forma total ou parcial.

Exemplos:

- Alguns softwares conseguem pegar um .jar e  transformar ele no arquivo de texto puro.
- Ferramentas CASE ou as vezes IDEs conseguem gerar diagrama de classes a partir de código fonte.

Comment: +1 Hum... Era  isso que queria saber. Obrigado @rray. Na verdade, esse termo apareceu de surpresa, quando estava pesquisando no google. Eu já falei que nesse ponto de terminologia eu não sou muito bom (porque não gosto muito desses termos, rsrsrsrs).

Comment: Seria como pegar o coffeescript de um javascript já compilado?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim, tem alguns outros usos.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters como vc acha que o pessoa monta crack de softwares :P?

Comment: não classificaria os diagramas gerados a partir do codigo fonte como eng. reversa uma vez que já tem o fonte, mas no caso do .jar concordo