# Como abrir um metadata no c#

Tags: c#

Tenho uma classe `ZipFile` em meu projeto. Nela há um método chamado `ExtractAll`, o qual é o método utilizado em minha rotina de extração de arquivo. Preciso olhar esse método(se for possível), pois quando eu extraio o arquivo zip, e tenho uma `pasta` com várias `pastas` dentro. Essa pasta está assim:

```
ws -> tiss -> v3 -> 02 -> 00
```

Na pasta `00` existe apenas um arquivo e essa é a última pasta do `unzip` e quando isso acontece, o último arquivo, da última pasta, da última sequência não está sendo extraído. Tem como abrir a classe ou não? Há solução para isso?

Comment: Utilize uma ferramenta como o Reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) para abrir a .dll contendo essa classe

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112817/o-que-%C3%A9-engenharia-reversa/112852

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade, seu comentário resolveu a minha necessidade. Se postar como resposta, eu voto e encerro o post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de visualizar um método de uma dll é utilizando um decompilador, como o [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/).

Para entender um pouco mais sobre decompiladores, sugiro que você dê uma olhada nessa pergunta aqui: [O que é Engenharia Reversa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112817/o-que-%C3%A9-engenharia-reversa/112852)