# Proteção de código .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho uma aplicação em C# que desenvolvi, ela será instalada em vários clientes. O problema é que tenho que proteger o código da aplicação, pois efetuei alguns testes com o aplicativo ILspy e todo o código fonte fica exposto. Qualquer um pode pegar uma DLL que você criou e copiar o código fonte. O Visual Studio 2015 já possui uma ferramenta para "ofuscar" o código, porém ela só altera o nome de algumas variáveis e métodos, uma pessoa com experiência em C# pode facilmente driblar isto.

Qual a solução mais viável para proteger o código fonte .NET?

Comment: Da uma olhada, tem uma lista aqui. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646707/something-better-than-net-reflector

Comment: @PauloHDSousa, essa lista é justamente o meu problema. Quero evitar que o código seja visto.

Comment: Da uma olhada na lista.

Comment: Ok, vou olhar sim.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Em uma resposta clara e sucinta, **NÃO TEM COMO!**

Digo que isso não é possível de fazer pelo fato de que por mais habilidoso que você seja, sempre terá alguém habilidoso o suficiente em [engenharia reversa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/112817/20615)  (ou outros tipos, incluindo engenharia social) para conseguir quebrar a sua proteção. Os [crack's](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crack_(software)) são a prova mais real sobre isso.

O que é possível fazer é dificultar o acesso, mas não existe uma forma que garanta 100% de proteção.

#### Mas então quer dizer que devo deixar da forma que está?

Isso depende muito. As vezes o trabalho que você terá para dificultar o acesso pode não ser viável por diversos fatores, por exemplo o tempo e custos para realizar essa tarefa.

#### Mas então não existe nada?

Bom, existem algumas ferramentas, para [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) em específico, que ajuda a realizar esse processo, que são:

- [DotOfuscador.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotfuscator)
- [Themida](http://www.oreans.com/)

#### Qual sua recomendação?

Não se preocupe muito com isso, pois se a pessoa tem capacidade para entender e usar um sistema de engenharia reversa e deixar o código funcionando, muitas vezes ela tem capacidade para fazer um igual, e as vezes o processo pode ser até mais rápido.

Agora, se seu problema seria com o uso indevido do sistema, você pode utilizar uma forma de licenças para assegurar a utilização do sistema.

#### Complementos:

Como complemento, deixo algumas perguntas aqui sobre o assunto, duas delas muito parecido com a sua.

- [Como proteger o código fonte?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7257/20615)
- [Protect .NET code from reverse engineering?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/506282/4843158)
- [O que é Engenharia Reversa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/112817/20615)

Comment: +1 pela resposta clara e sucinta.

Comment: Entendi, já havia pensado na questão da pessoa que tem capacidade para entender e usar um sistema de engenharia reversa. No caso de você desenvolver algo novo ou uma solução muito boa para algum problema e que queira proteger sua ideia, neste caso seria mais "fácil" desenvolver em c++ ou c ?

Comment: @Robss70 Entra no mesmo problema. Você pode dificultar, agora impedir não dá. [Esta resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6481695/4843158) fala sobre essa questão em `C++`

Comment: @Randrade, realmente esse assunto engenharia reversa e propriedade intelectual é extremamente complexo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Robss70 Propriedade intelectual é mais complexo ainda. Porém, se fizer tudo certo, estará amparado pela lei, mesmo que não consiga proteger o fonte terá a garantia que é seu. Com isso, poderá fazer algo judicialmente, se possível.

Comment: @Randrade, já abusando da sua boa vontade, no caso de string de conexão, como você protegeria esta informação no código fonte?

Comment: @Robss70 Isso irá depender do seu contexto. Depende do que está utilizando, com o que está trabalhando, como será essa conexão, etc. Eu geralmente não me preocupo muito com isso, pois meus sistemas ficam em um ambiente controlado e uso a autenticação do Windows.

Comment: É uma string de conexão Sql Server para uma banco de dados no Microsoft Azure, e o ambiente dos clientes são iguais ao velho oeste.

Comment: @Robss70 Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://eren.ws/2014/02/04/encrypting-the-web-config-file-of-an-azure-cloud-service/) e [aqui](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/securing-your-connection-string-in-windows-azure-part-1/). É uma forma, mas eu não conheço seu ambiente, então não tem como saber qual a melhor. Todavia, isso foge da pergunta original. Caso tenha mais dúvidas, o site já possui muito material sobre o assunto. Caso não ache nada, pode abrir outra pergunta sobre isso, especificamente.

Comment: @Randrade, mais uma vez muito obrigado pela sua atenção.

Answer (score 2):

Nenhuma técnica protegerá de fato, pode dificultar. Se está escondendo um segredo, está fazendo algo errado no código. Se não tem segredo, em geral os malefícios de fazer isso superam os benefícios. [Leia isso, é importante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7257/101).

Tem uma [lista na Wikipedia com ofuscadores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET). Obviamente a qualidade de cada fará um trabalho melhor. Algumas técnicas criam problemas para execução. É comum o desenvolvedor nem se dar conta que é o ofuscador o causador e sofrer sem necessidade. Há casos da pessoas que sempre acha que os problemas do seu código é o ofuscador.

Não sei qual é o melhor, principalmente para sua necessidade.

Mas começando principalmente em .NET 7 (antes era possível com alternativas mais complicadas de se adotar) é possível gerar código nativo, ou seja, o código de máquina o processador. Isso torna muito mais complicado obter o código original de volta, e não sei se tem alguma ferramenta pronta para uso que gere o C#, então é impossível para a maioria das pessoas. Não protege segredos, mas o trabalho de retomar o código original é tão grande quanto fazer do zero. Se isso bastar então **CONSEGUE TER A PROTEÇÃO QUE DESEJA**.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Já li a respeito destes problemas de execução, principalmente em reflection. Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda.