# Implementação de licença para software

Tags: licença, independente-de-linguagem

Pesquisando um poucos no fóruns, decidi fazer essa pergunta para ver como os desenvolvedores realizam a licença de um software. Por exemplo: quando se desenvolve um software, como vocês controlam o uso dele para evitar ao máximo a pirataria. Alguns desenvolvedores utilizam o número de série do HD, outros instalam a aplicação no servidor, dentre outras opções.

Comment: Complicada essa pergunta. Nenhum software está imune à pirataria. [Esses dias houve uma pergunta semelhante](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141721/prote%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-net/141734#141734).

Comment: Sim, isso eu sempre imaginei. Só queria um pouco da prática que é usada pelos desenvolvedores hoje @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: Cara, depende muito do que seu sistema ou software precisa para funcionar, um exemplo é um que estou a terminar aqui para empresa, ele usa se de WebService e Criptografia RSA para validar a utilização, porém se o usuário não tiver rede, ele fecha ou não executa (isso é um problema), mas há muitas outras formas pendente muito